If $f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$, then is $f(a)\cdot f(b)\leq f(a\cdot b)$?
Let $f(n)$ be the number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism.
We want to prove that:
$$f(a) \cdot f(b) \leq f(a \cdot b)$$
for all nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$.
Our progress:

If $a \cdot b \leq 8191$, then our conjecture holds.

If $a + b \leq 848$, then our conjecture holds.

If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then our conjecture holds.

If $a \cdot b$ has less than 5 primes in its integer factorization, then our conjecture holds.

If $f(a \cdot b) \leq 3$, then our conjecture holds.

Let $c$ and $d$ nonnegative integers.
Let $p$ a prime number.
If $c + d \leq 9$ or $c=d$ or $c\cdot(5\cdot c + 24) + d\cdot(5\cdot d + 24) \leq 17 \cdot c \cdot d + 9$ then
$$f(p^{c}) \cdot f(p^{d}) \leq f(p^{c + d})$$


Methods:
A lower bound of $f(2048)$ was used.
What are the tightest known bounds for the number of groups of order $2048$?
For all positive integers $a$ and $b$:
$$f(a) \leq f(a \cdot b)$$

If $a \cdot b = 0$, then our conjecture holds.
If $1\leq a \cdot b \leq 8191$:
37592 tests in an algorithm.

180625 tests in an algorithm.
If $f(65274) = 36$, then $36 \leq f(130548)$.

Thanks @testaccount.

Let $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ distinct prime numbers.
Study of 11 cases for $a \cdot b$: $p$, $p^{2}$, $p\cdot q$, $p^{3}$, $p^{2}\cdot q$, $p \cdot q \cdot r$, $p^{4}$, $p^{3} \cdot q$, $p^{2} \cdot q^{2}$, $p^{2} \cdot q \cdot r$, $p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot s$.

Our conjecture is valid for all squarefree $a \cdot b$.

https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf


Let $p$ a prime number and $m$ a positive integer.
$$p^{\frac{2}{27}m^{2}(m-6)} \leq f(p^{m}) \leq p^{\frac{1}{6}(m^{3}-m)}$$
Source:
https://groups.quendi.de/
Known bounds for the number of groups of a given order.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02616

@WhileIAm It's not so simple: $G_1 \times H_1$ could be isomorphic to $G_2 \times H_2$ although $G_1$ is not isomorphic to $G_2$ and $H_1$ not isomorphic to $H_2$.
Most notably, $G \times H$ is isomorphic to $H \times G$.

If, after a few days, no one has solved the question here, you might consider posting it to MathOverflow (making sure to link each post to the one on the other site).

The function $f$ has often been named ${\rm gnu}$, meaning "group number".

A nice article on the gnu function is here: https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf

This article above is really nice, and should definitely help you with this problem.

The conjecture was tested and found valid for a.b<50000 except the unknown values running 503330 tests on this database : https://github.com/olexandr-konovalov/gnu/blob/master/data/gnu50000.txt Of course the unknown values are the most interesting ones.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be representatives for the isomorphism classes of groups of orders $a$ and $b$, respectively. Maybe the set of all possible semidirect products ${A \rtimes B : A \in \mathcal{A}, B \in \mathcal{B}}$ contains at least $|\mathcal{A}| \cdot |\mathcal{B}|$ distinct groups, up to isomorphism. This would prove that $f(a)f(b) \leq f(ab)$.

Can you prove this when $a = p^2$ for a prime $p$? Surely $f(p^2 b) \geq 2 f(b)$?

@testaccount, I'm sorry. I don't know how to prove when $a=p^{2}$.
